# How to avoid cells when using parfor for the below code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance

I have this code and I want to use parfor instead of regular for loop to improve the computation time. When i tried to run the code it gave errors

Please suggest an equivalent code which allows me to use parfor for the below code

```
for i = 1:l % l = size of image data set = 9907
    IDB{1,i} = imread(strcat(path,strcat(num2str(i),'.jpg')));
    Icolor{1,i} = colorMoments(IDB{1,i}); % 6-features in each cell
    Iwave{1,i} = waveletTransform(IDB{1,i}); % 8-features in each cell
    IglrlFeatures{1,i}  = textureFeatures(IDB{1,i}); % 44-features in each cell
    ICW{1,i} = [Icolor{1,i} Iwave{1,i} IglrlFeatures{1,i}];
end
```

Thanks,

Gopi

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preallocate cell array size before loop

```
IDB = cell(1,l)
Icolor = ...
...
```

Access each cell as a single memory item with  `()` instead of `{}`. I've also change the first indexing from constant `1` to literal `:`. I'm not sure which is causing your error but generally, when `parfor` doesn't execute for multidimensional structures it's because your "slices" of the structure don't align with parfor sliced representation. Usually one of these will make your representation parfor-accessible.

```
for i = 1:l
  IDB(:,i) = imread(...)
  Icolor(:,i) = colorMoments(IDB(:,i)); 
  ...
end
```

Comment: I pre-allocated for each cell and used IDB{1,i} indexing inside and the time complexity improved from 91secs (for loop) to 31secs (parfor loop) for the program I was using. I don't know why did IDB(:,i) didn't work but now I can use parfor loops thank you so much..

Comment: so out of curiosity when we start parallel pool on MATLAB it said 4 workers  running , so what does it mean? Can we give more parallel workers and does it improve computation time even better?

Comment: That means it creates 4 threads for parallel processes. Your thread size is limited by the number of cores you have in you computer, most are in the 2-8 range but that can certainly vary. Any time you create more processes you risk reducing speedup at the cost of overhead communication. Generally speaking, tasks that have a lot of data broadcast to each thread, short thread execution times, or low number of processes to run are at risk of taking longer if more threads are added.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now i understand a little about parallel pool